# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hi everyone I keep getting this error java.lang.NullPointerException
can you please help me fix it

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++){
            Movie movie = (Movie) ((Object[]) lst.get(i))[0];
            Category c = (Category) ((Object[]) lst.get(i))[1];
            if(movie == null){
                System.out.println("the Object movie is null");
                movie = (Movie) ((Object[]) lst.get(i))[0];
                Movie_List.add(movie);
            }else{
                Movie_List.add(movie);
            }
        }
```

even if I do the test to see if the object movie is null it does not show the message so it is not null so what is the problem? please help me

Comment: Holy crap, storing lists of objects of totally different kinds in one array... This begs for trouble... That's why we have objects, right?

Comment: Debug the program and you will find out the problem.

Comment: The exception stack trace points at the line with the error.  On that line one or more pointers ("object references") will appear.  One of those is null.  If you don't have a better way to debug it, insert println statements to figure out which reference is the problem.  This is known as debugging, and is what real programmers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the NullPointerException occurs on this line

```
Movie_List.add(movie);
```

then the list Movie_List is null. You should initialise it with

```
Movie_List = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

By the way, the list would be better named as movieList or even better movies.